# Error with eloquent query

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I'm using Laravel 5.0

I want basically this type of query:

> (a='x' and b='y') or (a='xy')

With `users` having `books`:

```
    $users= \App\User::whereHas('books', function($q) use ($x, $y){
        $q->where(function ($query) use ($x, $y){
            $query->where('a','=', $x)->where('b', '=',$y);
        })
        ->orWhere(function ($query2) use ($x, $y){
            $query2->where('a','=',$x.$y);
        });
    });
```

Of course I have in User:

```
public function books()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Book');
}
```

But if a check the SQL generated through `"toSql()"` I get this:

```
  from users where (select count(*) from books where 
    users.book_id = books.id 
    and 
    (a = ? and b = ?) 
    or 
    (a = ?)
  ) >= 1
```

which obviously is not the intended query, because it is provoking the `users.book_id=books.id` part optional, resulting in much more results than should.

So, my question is: What am I doing wrong in my eloquent query?

Comment: Just a note, have you considered using DB::Raw instead?

Comment: @LewisJohnson : No, because I need to return models, not table entries.

Comment: So you can use hydrateRaw no?

Comment: I don't know, but is it possible to get the result I desire only with eloquent ?

Comment: what is the value of $x and $y?? did you assign any value to this variable??

Comment: Yes, I assign values to those variables. I think that their value is irrelevant.

Comment: i exactly run a query like you and the output is `select * from `users` where exists (select * from `user_profile` where `users`.`id` = `user_profile`.`user_id` and ((`a` = ? and `b` = ?) or (`a` = ?)))`. Seems fine from my end, right?

Comment: i am using L 5.4

Comment: Have you tried `whereRaw` as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to have two different nested wheres.  The entire grouping should all be within the same parentheses.

```
$users= \App\User::whereHas('books', function($q) use ($x, $y){
    $q->where(function ($query) use ($x, $y){
        $query->where('a','=', $x)
              ->where('b', '=',$y)
              ->orWhere('a','=',$x.$y);
    });
});
```

A and B or C is functionally equivalent to (A and B) or (C)